# What are Spring Security default credentials for Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hateoas

I am working with `Spring Boot` and I am using `spring-data-rest-hal-browser`, everything seems to be fine, except when i try to hit the URL: `http://localhost:8080` I get redirected to `http://localhost:8080/login` to use the HAL browser to navigate my endpoint, then I get a screen requesting for a user and a password that I don't have.

What are the default credentials to login to spring security and how can I change them or disable the login option?

This is the dependency I am using:

```xml
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-browser</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And this is the login screen:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at the console output after running your application. If you have no run-time exceptions, then you should easily find the credentials. By default the username is `user` and the password is always different and therefore generated from the system.

For more clarity, the login page comes with this dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Also, if you want to set some values for the credentials, then go to the `application.properties` file and add those two lines:

```
spring.security.user.name=<your/username>
spring.security.user.password=<your/password>
```

Comment: This solved my problem. Thanks for clarifying the fact that the login page comes with the spring security dependency and for pointing the way to set my own creds to avoid having new one every time i restart my project. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Default username is `user`

password can be found in the console when you run your application.

example:

```
Using generated security password: 18ea5687-bc63-4663-9377-e2817c9d2568
```

If you want to set them yourself you can do so by overriding the defaults in `application.properties`:

```
spring.security.user.name=stack
spring.security.user.password=overflow
```